# Update or insert mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find a solution to update or insert value in my MySQL table (like in firebird you have `UPDATE OR INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (VAL1, VAL2, VAL3) MATCHING (COL1, COL2)`.

I know MySQL have `on duplicate key` but I do not want that! I do not want to set a key on some of my columns because that one table is used depending on the situation.

So is there any other way of performing `update or insert` action?

Comment: so based on what you update or insert if you dont want to use key ?

Comment: i have table with 3 columns. `OneID, OtherID, JsonObject`. In some part of code i want to do it based on `OtherID` only, in some on `OneID and OtherID` and in some on `OneID`

Comment: If no key is set, how should MySQL determine that you want to update an existing row?

Comment: that is my question. In firebird i can do just like i wrote above with `UPDATE OR INSERT` and `MATCHING`

Comment: 'So is there any other way of performing update or insert actoin' - no there isn't, mysql is way behind other rdbms in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

if I remember correctly COL1 should be unique

```
INSERT INTO table
      (COL1, COL2, COL3)
    VALUES
      (?, ?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      COL2 = VALUES(COL2)
    COL2 = VALUES(COL2 )
```